# Problem creating a point IFeatureClass

Tags: arcobjects, point, vb.net

I'm trying to create a point IFeatureClass, but my code doesn't work.

```
Public Function CreatePointFeatureClass(ByVal featureClassName As String, _
                                         ByVal featureWorkspace As IFeatureWorkspace) As IFeatureClass

    ' Instantiate a feature class description to get the required fields.
    Dim fcDescription As IFeatureClassDescription = New FeatureClassDescriptionClass()
    Dim ocDescription As IObjectClassDescription = CType(fcDescription, IObjectClassDescription)

    Dim fields As IFields = New FieldsClass
    Dim fieldsEdit As IFieldsEdit = CType(fields, IFieldsEdit)
    Dim fieldUserDefined As IField = New FieldClass
    Dim fieldEdit As IFieldEdit = CType(fieldUserDefined, IFieldEdit)

    ' Set up geometry definition for the Shape field.
    ' You do not have to set the spatial reference, as it is inherited from the feature dataset.
    Dim geometryDef As IGeometryDef = New GeometryDefClass
    Dim geometryDefEdit As IGeometryDefEdit = CType(geometryDef, IGeometryDefEdit)

    ' By setting the grid size to 0, you are allowing ArcGIS to determine the appropriate grid sizes for the feature class. 
    ' If in a personal geodatabase, the grid size is 1,000. If in a file or ArcSDE geodatabase, the grid size
    ' is based on the initial loading or inserting of features.
    geometryDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint

    ' Set standard field properties.
    fieldEdit.Name_2 = "SHAPE"
    fieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry
    fieldEdit.GeometryDef_2 = geometryDefEdit
    fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = True
    fieldEdit.Required_2 = True
    fieldsEdit.AddField(fieldUserDefined)


    ' Add a X Double field to the required fields.
    Dim field1 As IField = New FieldClass()
    Dim fieldEdit1 As IFieldEdit = CType(field1, IFieldEdit)
    fieldEdit1.Name_2 = "X"
    fieldEdit1.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDouble
    fieldsEdit.AddField(field1)

    ' Add a Y Double field to the required fields.
    Dim field2 As IField = New FieldClass()
    Dim fieldEdit2 As IFieldEdit = CType(field2, IFieldEdit)
    fieldEdit2.Name_2 = "Y"
    fieldEdit2.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDouble
    fieldsEdit.AddField(field2)

    ' Add a Elevation Double field to the required fields.
    Dim field3 As IField = New FieldClass()
    Dim fieldEdit3 As IFieldEdit = CType(field3, IFieldEdit)
    fieldEdit3.Name_2 = "Elevation"
    fieldEdit3.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDouble
    fieldsEdit.AddField(field3)




    ' Use IFieldChecker to create a validated fields collection.
    Dim fieldChecker As IFieldChecker = New FieldCheckerClass()
    Dim enumFieldError As IEnumFieldError = Nothing
    Dim validatedFields As IFields = Nothing
    fieldChecker.ValidateWorkspace = CType(featureWorkspace, IWorkspace)
    fieldChecker.Validate(fields, enumFieldError, validatedFields)

    ' The enumFieldError enumerator can be inspected at this point to determine
    ' which fields were modified during validation.
    ' Create the feature class.
    Dim featureClass As IFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(featureClassName, validatedFields, _
                                    ocDescription.InstanceCLSID, ocDescription.ClassExtensionCLSID, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, _
                                    "SHAPE", "")

    Return featureClass

End Function
```

Comment: Try not to scare away the n00bs!  It's definitely down-vote worthy, but he joined today.  I suggest commenting first and give him a shot to redeem the question before chucking down-votes at the question (maybe a few hours after the next 'last seen' time) .  Otherwise he may flee to the Esri forums and never look back!

Comment: if you have some sources that can helps me , please write down here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says you have to add a valid spatial reference to your geometryDefEdit object.

Add these lines after the creation of your geometryDef object (taken from http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/ArcObjects/esriGeodatabase/IFeatureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass_Example.htm)

```
        Dim spatialReferenceFactory As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ISpatialReferenceFactory3 = New     ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass()
        Dim spatialReference As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ISpatialReference = spatialReferenceFactory.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriSRProjCSType.esriSRProjCS_NAD1983UTM_20N)
        Dim spatialReferenceResolution As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ISpatialReferenceResolution = CType(spatialReference, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ISpatialReferenceResolution)
        spatialReferenceResolution.ConstructFromHorizon()
        Dim spatialReferenceTolerance As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ISpatialReferenceTolerance = CType(spatialReference, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ISpatialReferenceTolerance)
        spatialReferenceTolerance.SetDefaultXYTolerance()
        geometryDefEdit.SpatialReference_2 = spatialReference
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Goldorak84 said, you're missing a spatial reference.

Might I suggest making a utility method,  that's like this.  Sorry using C# here.

```
static public ISpatialReference GetSpatialReference()
{

ISpatialReference spatialReference;

ISpatialReferenceFactory3 spatialReferenceFactory = 
new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();
spatialReference = spatialReferenceFactory.CreateSpatialReference((int)esriRSGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WSG1984);

return spatialReference;

}
```

Obviously you'll want to set your resolution and tolerance in there as well.

Comment: SpatialReferenceEnvironment is a singleton and as such should be instantiated via Activator.CreateInstance instead the **new** operator. See http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Interacting_with_singleton_objects/00010000043p000000/

Answer (score 0):

Minor Typo ,Replace esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984 with
esriRSGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WSG1984